# Generating function of specific signature with known return value

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Is there a way to generate a static function (pointer) that:
 1. Is of specific signature.
 2. Returns specific value.
 3. Ignores all arguments.

Something like:

```
template<typename ReturnType, ReturnType defaultValue, typename... Args>
ReturnType FallbackFunction(Args... ) {
    return defaultValue;
}

int threeParamFunction(int one, int two, int three)
{
    return one + two + three;
}

float twoParamFunction(float one, float two)
{
    return one + two;
}

int main()
{
    // This somehow works
    using ThreeParamFunction = decltype(&threeParamFunction);
    ThreeParamFunction fncPointerZero = FallbackFunction<int, 0>;
    cout << "Returning zero: " << fncPointerZero(5, 10, 15) << std::endl;
    ThreeParamFunction fncPointerOne = FallbackFunction<int, 1>;
    cout << "Returning one: " << fncPointerOne(5, 10, 15) << std::endl;

    // Does not compile:
    //using TwoParamFunction = decltype(&twoParamFunction);
    //TwoParamFunction fncPointerSeven = FallbackFunction<float, 7.0f>;
    //cout << "Returning seven: " << fncPointerSeven(5, 10) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Motivation is to generate a fallback function that returns known value, if application is unable to load proper function.

Comment: "ignores"? ... or `std::forward`s?

Comment: Where is twoParamFunction defined?

Comment: Why not just set the function pointer to `nullptr`, and check the function is not null before calling it?   Also, in your example, what's wrong with `int threeParamFunctionBackup(int, int, int) {return some_default_value;}`?

Comment: @Peter In most cases you are right. But if you have functions like isSomethingEnabled, isSomethingPresent loaded dynamically and used all over the code, you do not have to validate pointer before every call.

Comment: In that case, the `isSomethingEnabled` should not be dynamically loaded.  It should be a single function that checks if the dynamically loaded function has been loaded before calling it.   If your user code is expecting to call a dynamically loaded function everywhere, it needs to validate that function first.

Comment: I understand it's cleaner, but this can reduce performance of optimistic scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot take address/type of template function (but you can for specific instances).

so your

```
auto f0 = &FallbackFunction<int, 0>; // decltype(f0) is `int (*)()` not `int (*)(Ts...)`
```

but indeed, in your case

```
int (*fncPointer)(int, int, int) = &FallbackFunction<int, 0>;
// Only FallbackFunction<int, 0, int, int, int> is valid
// it is mostly static_cast<int (*)(int, int, int)>(&FallbackFunction<int, 0>)
// Which force deduction to FallbackFunction<int, 0, int, int, int>.
```

So either specify all arguments:

```
auto f2 = &FallbackFunction<int, 0, int, int>; // decltype(f2) is `int (*)(int, int)`
```

Or you can create functor with `operator()` (with lambda):

```
auto foo = [](auto...){ return 0; };
foo(); foo(1); foo(1, 2, 3);

auto bar = [](auto...){ return 4.2f; };
bar(); bar(1); bar(1, 2, 3);
```

In addition, `float` is not a valid non-type parameter:

```
template <float f> struct S{}; // invalid.
```

Comment: The more interesting question seems to be, why does the first version work at all? And how is it any different from the second function type. [Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zAk9vpVQHbIpxpQ7).

Comment: @super: Miss that point. `float` is not a valid non-type parameter.

Comment: Great, I can take this functor and assign it to pointer, it will deduct proper type. I just need separate functor for each return type.